# Casting a Generic EntitySet returned by Reflection as an EntitySet with a BaseClass Type

Tags: c#-4.0, generics, inheritance, reflection, casting

I am having an issue when casting a Generic EntitySet returned by Reflection as an EntitySet with a BaseClass Type.

All of my Linq2Sql classes inherit from a base class named LinqClassBase like this:

```
public partial class MyTable1 : LinqClassBase
```

I am writing a method in that base class that needs to iterate through all child EntitySets.

I can retrieve the PropertyInfo OK as matchingEntitySetProperty.

```
// The GetMatchingProperty method (not shown) 
// simply gets all the properties with Type EntitySet
var matchingProperty = entitySetProperty.GetMatchingProperty(this.GetType());
```

I can also get it's value OK.

```
// This returns EntitySet<MyTable1>
var matchingSet = matchingProperty.GetValue(this);
```

The problem here is that I can't call the ToList method because the object isn't strongly typed.

```
var newList = matchingSet.ToList().ConvertAll(
  x => x.MyLinqBaseClassMethod()
);
```

I tried casting it as EntitySet but it returns null:

```
// This returns null
var matchingSet = matchingProperty.GetValue(this) as EntitySet<LinqClassBase>;
```

Why does this cast return null? I'm guessing because C# can't cast EntitySet to EntitySet.

Ff this cast isn't possible, is there another way to Cast it?

Note: I thought about using another layer of Reflection to call the ToList method, but then I would run into the same problem for the ConvertAll method and again for the MyLinqBaseClassMethod.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Casting it to IEnumerable gives me access to the ToList method and doesn't cause it to return a null.

```
var matchingSet = matchingProperty.GetValue(this) as IEnumerable<LinqClassBase>;
```

I still don't know why casting it has EntitySet fails. But at least I have my solution.